# Как мне не допустить множественное нажатие на кнопку в телеграмм боте на питоне? (Aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Пишу новостного телеграмм бота на питоне. Пользователь выбирает сайт, а затем выбирает номер новости. Бот предлагает на выбор 3 сайта, при нажатии на кнопку, бот начинает парсить сайт. Если же пользователь многократно нажмёт на кнопку, то бот ломается. Ниже приведён пример той самой кнопки, не судите строго, первый раз пишу на питоне)

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="SecurityLab"))
async def News(message: types.Message):
   await message.reply("Сейчас что-нибудь поищу.", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
   global browser
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   SecurityLab_News.parsing_Secure_lab(browser)

   n = 1
   for i in range(0, len(SecurityLab_News.news_title) - 11):
       await message.answer(str(n) + ')' + ' ' + SecurityLab_News.news_title[i].text)
       n += 1

   keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   keyboard.add(*buttons_Seclab)
   await message.answer("Введите номер новости.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Как мне избежать многократного нажатия на кнопку в aiogram?

Comment: а если удалять кнопку? те -> нажали на кнопку -> удаляем её -> парсим. При этом можно осуществить меню которое будет постоянно возвращаться после клика по кнопке одного из сайта. https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/reply_keyboard_remove.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def throttle(self, target: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery]):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if not handler:
            return
        limit = getattr(handler, 'throttling_rate_limit', self.rate_limit)
        key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")

        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            await self.target_throttled(target, t, dispatcher, key)
            raise CancelHandler()

    @staticmethod
    async def target_throttled(target: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery],
                               throttled: Throttled, dispatcher: Dispatcher, key: str):
        msg = target.message if isinstance(target, types.CallbackQuery) else target
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        if throttled.exceeded_count == 2 :
            await msg.reply('Слишком Часто! Давай не так быстро')
            return
        elif throttled.exceeded_count == 3:
            await msg.reply(f'⚠ Всё. Больше не отвечу, пока не пройдет {round(delta, 3)} секунд')
            return
        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count:
            await msg.reply("⚠ Все, теперь отвечаю.")

    async def on_process_message(self, message, data):
        await self.throttle(message)

    async def on_process_callback_query(self, call, data):
        await self.throttle(call)
```

```
def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, "throttling_key", key)
        return func

    return decorator
```

Должно работать, просто устанавливая декоратор над функцией и передавая сколько секунд нужно подождать, если нужна более точная настройка, можно передавать в декоратор второй параметр key='your_param' и уже в функции target_throttled строить свою логику

```
@rate_limit(limit=5)
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="SecurityLab"))
async def News(message: types.Message):
   await message.reply("Сейчас что-нибудь поищу.", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
   global browser
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   SecurityLab_News.parsing_Secure_lab(browser)

   n = 1
   for i in range(0, len(SecurityLab_News.news_title) - 11):
       await message.answer(str(n) + ')' + ' ' + SecurityLab_News.news_title[i].text)
       n += 1

   keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   keyboard.add(*buttons_Seclab)
   await message.answer("Введите номер новости.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку "This storage does not provide Leaky Bucket". Не понимаю, с чем это связано.